# How to take particular value from json response in php

Tags: php, json

My Json String looks like this:

Now i wanted to take only value of ID as an Integer:

```
[{"Obj" :    
        { "ID":"11",
          "NAME":"XYZ",
          "GENDER":"M" 
        }
}]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `json_decode`. See here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833737/php-json-decode-how-to-output-array

Comment: I tried using json_decode and also using $this->Obj->ID but it returns same string as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the json output using `json_decode` and put `true` as second parameter. It will give you array output.

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
echo $arr[0]['Obj']['ID'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php
    $json='[{"Obj" :    
            { "ID":"11",
              "NAME":"XYZ",
              "GENDER":"M" 
            }
    }]';
    $jsonArray=json_decode($json);
    echo $jsonArray[0]->Obj->ID;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your json string is inside a post parameter:

```
$json_string = $_POST['json'];
```

using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) you can convert a json string to a php object:

```
$json = json_decode($json_string);
```

and then access to your ID:

```
$id = $json[0]->Obj->ID;
```

if you want to convert the object into associative array just do this:

```
$json = (array)$json;
```

and access to your id:

```
$id = $json[0]['Obj']['ID'];
```