# Decoding json received from ajax in php file

Tags: jquery

I am passing json object to my php file through ajax call.

jQuery Syntax

```
$.getJSON('http:..Sample/JsonCreation.php', function(data)
{
   //data has the json - I am trying to edit this json and then pass it to another php file through ajax and save in DB. I have successfully edited but unable to access the passed json in my php file.
   questionsArray = data;
}
$('form').on('submit', function(event)
{
//AJAX CALL
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "updateTestReport.php",
                    type: "post",
                    //JSON.stringify
                    data: {json:(questionsArray)},
                    contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype: "text",

                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //alert("success");
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
                });
});
```

PHP FILE

```
<?php

//$contentjson = file_get_contents("php://input");
//echo $_POST['json'];
$questionsArray = json_encode($_POST['json']);
echo $questionsArray;


?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
[{"questionNumber":"1","quesDesc":"The price of petrol has increased by 25%.By what percentage should it now be reduced to return to the original price?","optionA":"25%","optionB":"20%","optionC":"15%","optionD":null,"correctOption":"A","selectedAnswer":null,"isQuestionViewed":null},{"questionNumber":"2","quesDesc":"Price of cooking gas has increased by 10%. By what percentage should consumption be reduced to keep expenditure unchanged?","optionA":"9.09%","optionB":"10%","optionC":"11.11%","optionD":null,"correctOption":"A","selectedAnswer":null,"isQuestionViewed":null},{"questionNumber":"3","quesDesc":"A buys a shirt for Rs 100 and sells it to B for Rs 120. B now sells it to C for Rs 144. Had A sold it directly to C at the price C paid for it, then his profit % would have been","optionA":"10%","optionB":"20%","optionC":"44%","optionD":null,"correctOption":"C","selectedAnswer":null,"isQuestionViewed":null}]
```

1) How is that json_encode in the php file gives the output. Shouldn't i use json_decode? 
2) And even through the encoded json, i am not able to retrieve the values. Please let me know how to access the values from this json...
3) what is the difference between file_get_contents & $_POST['json']?

EDIT:
//BEGIN

I need to access my json inside the php file, retrieve some values, make some calculations, save in DB. Then return to the main html file.

//END
Kindly give clear explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I am giving you an example for the ajax for submission.
form#data -> #data is the id of the form

```
<script>
    $("form#data").submit(function() {
        if($("form#data").validationEngine('validate') != true){
         return false;
         }
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/test.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if (data.result == true) {
                    alert('Your details updated successfully.');
                }
                else if (data.result == false) {
                    alert("Your details not updated!");
                }
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Now I am showing you the test.php which was requested on ajax call.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' )) {
    $mt = $_POST['tmt'];
    if($mt!=NULL){
            $res11['result']=TRUE;
        }else{
            $res11['result']=FALSE;
        }
        echo json_encode($res11);
}
?>
```

This is the php file which get the data through the ajax post. If you have any queries or other queries, you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly printing the values by alert, it will display `[Object]` because the response is in JSON format. Try `alert(res[0].questionNumber)`, this will display first questionNumber

Try something like this to access the values

```
success: function(res)
{
 for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++)
 {
    qno = res[i].questionNumber;
    desc = res[i].quesDesc;
    // and so on
    // do whatever you want this data
 }
},
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833737/php-json-decode-how-to-output-array and http://in1.php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert or fetch the array which you have encoded in php. I have given you the solution for the ajax

```
<script>
            $.ajax
                    ({
                        url: "updateTestReport.php",
                        type: "post",
                        //JSON.stringify
                        data: {json: (questionsArray)},
                        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype: "text",
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            /*
                             * Below this comment you can also use 
                             * data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                             * It will decode json encoded
                             */
                            data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                            alert(data.questionNumber);
                            alert(data.quesDesc);
                            /*
                             * put the array keys using the period in between with data variable
                             * 
                             */
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            alert("failure");
                        }
                    });
        </script>
```

Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: Sorry if i haven't placed my query clearly.I need to access json inside the php file.... I am echo'ing in my php just to check the output...

Comment: @vivin You can use json_decode($_POST['json']) for your php and can use the array

Comment: I did try @Avi. But in my alert it gives a huge message having html content - <br /> <font size = '1'> <table.....

Comment: @vivin This is kind of error. Will you please tell me exact message which is coming as alert.

Comment: I found the warning message... json_decode()expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in... I am trying to use JSON.stringify. But even the preventDefault() action of the submit button is not executed. Why is it so?

Comment: I am using Eclipse PDT and wamp server. What options can i try?

Comment: ok, this is because when you are echoing values from there either you have to use array with json_encode at php or remove data=data.parseJson(data); from ajax script to get the data. Please let me know if you have any queries

Comment: data=data.parseJson(data); What is this for @avi? I tried but nothing is happening. And chrome is better than the eclipse browser, it shows some errors...

Comment: Actually this is decoding the Json output which has been encoded in your php script.